# gitlab error: Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 10 commit you are not allowed to push code to protected branch

Tags: git, gitlab

When I merge branches with the main branch, I merge them directly with the main branch, forgetting to push to the remote branch, and then merge and push the main branch, which shows that there are 10 unplugged submissions that can not complete the push. How can I handle this error?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please add your error messages as text, not as an image.

Comment: Is it your own personal repo? Do you work with other people on it? Are you the maintainer of that repo?

Answer (score 3):

A normal approach would be to create and push a new branch from master and then raise a pull request against the master branch.

You can create a new branch from master using

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Another way which I would not recommend to use will be to remove the restrictions if you are the admin of the repository and don't want to use the solution mentioned above

**NOTE:** The sole purpose of protected branches is to reject the force push and normal push from everyone but the users with such permissions

Read more here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html